# how to tune MySQL 5.6 database

Tags: mysql, performance

We're developing an enterprise product that uses MySQL 5.6 on Windows to store reports generated by multiple clients. Our database contains approximately 20 tables, each table containing ranging from a few hundred thousand to some million records. All tables have more than 10 columns with a combination of numeric and textual data. All tables use innodb engine with numeric field as primary key. The tables are indexed on another numeric field, different than the primary key.

There are about 10 connections used to merge new data into the database. The data is viewed via a web console. There is as such no limit on the number of instances on viewing the data. We also don't have any reference/foreign key in tables so we don't use joins.

We haven't created stored procedure for fetching data. Does the store procedure really improve performance?

While searching solution on the internet, I found that if we changes the values of innodb_buffer_pool_size, read_rnd_buffer_size, sort_buffer_size etc fields in my.ini/my.cnf files, then we can improve performance as well as minimize memory requirements of mysql. But I am not confident about it because I don't know what should be the proper values of it and what are the side effect of it. Currently I kept the default configuration. Please let me know which values can be changed in the configuration file to improve performance and minimize memory requirements without any side effect.

I would also like to know some other ways to optimize & fine tune MySQL engine that would boost the performance & use optimum resources.

Minimum software/hardware requirement of our product is : 
    OS  : Windows 2000 SP4 Professional / Server and later.
    RAM : 1 GB
    CPU : 1 GHz.

Answer (score 0):

There are no predefined values for defined for performance in any database and if they are present then they are already used in default configurations.

So first time think about schema design. If your schema is designed well then you have already resolved half the issues.
From your description schema looks good as you already have applied indexes,no joins etc.

First try your application with default setting provided by Mysql engine.
Then carry out performance test of your application's critical/widely used/resource intensive workflow. (definition of these terms varies per application.)

If you find performance bottlenecks on database side then try below things,

1. Check heavy queries used by application. optimize them
2. if queries cannot be optimized then make them faster using indexes
3. carry out regular tuning of database (fragmentations,runstats etc.)
4. if you see bufferpools shortage,sort overflow,read buffers then tune them accordingly which is not one time job.
   Performance tuning is very difficult job, requires lot of patience and expertise.
5. And Yes, generally stored procedures helps to improve performance. apply them whenever you can move heavy code logic into database.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: We ship mysql server with our product, So we cannot modify the settings once release. Manual intervention to change the settings are not possible, it needs to be automated. We used mysql++ library to manipulate DB. Also, I have checked all queries, our heaviest query contains group by on 3 columns, where one of it is numeric indexed key.

Comment: Also, I have observed that when I query first time it takes some time to execute (about 1 min) but when I execute same query second time the result comes much faster (10-15 Sec.). May be it is because of caching, so is it possible to cache the result of the query, so that it gives faster results for the first time?

Comment: see though you ship the product still you can send fix patches whenever required. that is why I am saying test your app for performance first. create workload model on your side.test it on staging environment and then tune it and then release your product with deployment guide which contains the tunings. Though you release it, DB and app are generally diff things, tuning database parameters will never hamper application logic and they can be changed in between.